# group values by price decimal and sum by quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, group-by

I would like to Group Object of Array by price and sum by quantity in javascript? For example:

```
var array=[
  {price:0.112,qty:1},
  {price:0.218,qty:1},
  {price:0.216,qty:1},
  {price:0.321,qty:1},
  {price:0.325,qty:2},
  {price:0.335,qty:2},
  {price:0.536,qty:1}
]
```

After I Group it by the `price` with price `decimal` I will get the new Array like:

price `decimal=2`, is expected output:

```
[
  {price:0.32,qty:3},
  {price:0.33,qty:2},
  {price:0.53,qty:1}
]
```

price decimal=1, get_number=2  is expected output:

```
[
  {price:0.3,qty:5},
  {price:0.5,qty:1}
]
```

Comment: Where does `qty:5` and `qty:3` in the output come from?

Comment: Please provide the JavaScript that you tried in the form of a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple **[`Array#forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** call to iterate over the `array` values and filter them by `price` using **[`.toFixed()`method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)**:

```
let result = [];
array.forEach(function(a) {
  a.price = a.price.toFixed(1);
  if (result.some(x => x.price === a.price)) {
    result.find(x => x.price === a.price).qty += a.qty;
  } else {
    result.push(a);
  }
});
```

Here  `.toFixed(1)` will compare prices using only one decimal, if you want to compare with two decimals, you just need to chnage it to `.toFixed(2)`.

**Demo:**

This is a working snippet:

```js
var array=[
  {price:0.112,qty:1},
  {price:0.218,qty:1},
  {price:0.216,qty:1},
  {price:0.321,qty:1},
  {price:0.325,qty:2},
  {price:0.335,qty:2},
  {price:0.536,qty:1}
]

let result = [];
array.forEach(function(a) {
  a.price = a.price.toFixed(1);
  if (result.some(x => x.price === a.price)) {
    result.find(x => x.price === a.price).qty += a.qty;
  } else {
    result.push(a);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```